# How was the reputation computed for those of us who merged from brewadvice?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Before the homebrew/brewadvice merger, I had more reputation on brewadvice than I do now after the merge. I'm not here for the points, but I am curious as to how this was handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your answer can be found in the:  https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/faq

The point system did change between brewadvice.com and homebrew.stackexchange.com - for details you can read:  http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/

The largest change - up votes on questions are now worth +5 instead of +10.

Comment: OK. So my old actions have been rescored with under the new system. Got it. Thanks.